# NSDate - Setting a future date

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate

Facing some problem in setting up future date. Actually I m trying to do this,

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date] + MY_EXTRA_TIME;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That should be,

```
NSTimeInterval MY_EXTRA_TIME = 10; // 10 Seconds
NSDate *futureDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:MY_EXTRA_TIME];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift**

```
let delay:NSTimeInterval = 5
let fireDate = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(delay)
```